# Can a separate thread change static variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, static

After surfing the web, I am still confused about the following thread behavior. I am aware that static variables are shared within the same classloader, however there's sth definitely missing in this extract:

```
public class parallelCounter {
    public static final int N = 100000000;
    public static int j = 0;
    public static void inc() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(j); // 10000000
    }
}

class parallelCounterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parallelCounter.inc();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        System.out.println(parallelCounter.j); // 0 Why?
    }
}
```

Comment: As alluded to below; 't1' hasn't started (or at least, finished) by the time you print the value.  Try 't1.join()' after starting it. This will wait for it to finish before continuing.

Comment: ..yes, you have to `t1.join()` (or wait) to expect any values calculated by `inc()`

Comment: Thanks much, community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t1 is a new Thread which start asynchronous and your code continue without calling inc() function so j number is still 0

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to note here:

1. Your code has a race-condition in that the state when printing depends on the execution speed of the two independent threads. Most times `t1` will not even have started executing `inc` when your `println` executes. You might try adding a `sleep(100)` or something after `t1.start`.
2. You have to take care that not all changes to variables made by one thread will be instantly visible to other threads - this is a pretty complex topic where you have to check which constucts will result in data-synchronization between threads. For you example the easiest way could be to declare `j` as `public static volatile int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, in the current state, has a concurrency issue as two Threads try to access the static int variable at the same time (**without synchronization**):

- `Main Thread` tries to read the value of the variable
- `t1 Thread` tries to write the value of the variable

The `Syso` outputs 0, because the `run` method of the t1 thread hasn't started yet (no increments were done). But this is not 100% guaranteed to happen all the time.

If you want to be sure that the `t1` thread finishes its execution before doing the `Syso` in main, you should use the [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) method:

```
public class parallelCounter {
    public static final int N = 100000000;
    public static int j = 0;
    public static void inc() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(j); // 10000000
    }
}

class parallelCounterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parallelCounter.inc();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join(); // Wait for thread to finish
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(parallelCounter.j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `System.out.println(parallelCounter.j);`, your `parallelCounter.inc();` function in your thread still hasn't ended. So `j`'s value is still unincremented, at 0. Replace your `for` loop by a simple assignment, and add a `Thread.sleep(1000);` after starting your `Thread t1`, and you'll get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I did not run your code, but I assume that the method call 
`System.out.println(parallelCounter.j);` occured to soon within the program's execution flow.

You started the thread and then your code prints the value of `j` immediately.
I think that the thread did not have enough time to start the run() method.

I suggest that you insert some waiting period before you print `j`, e.g.

`Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000); // 3 seconds wait`

Comment: Be careful with this duration: he has to iterate a million time, so if the code doesn't get optimized by the compiler, 3 seconds will probably be too short.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Nathan ... I suggested the 3 second wait just to see how the value changed properly. For outputing the correct and final value a join would be the best solution, e.g. `t1.join()` to wait until the thread has finished.